# how to take the xml file from soapobject

Tags: android, web-services, xmldocument, ksoap

I receive xmldocument from .net web service 
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

and the problem is how to take the xml document from the result and parse it?

Comment: Do you want to access the SOAP XML response and parse it manually?

Comment: i want to see the xmldocument that i receive from the web service so...

Comment: But why are you using then kSoap - kSoap parses the response and allows you to access the parameters by their index and/or name? If you want to parse the response XML on your own you should do everything by hand and use HTTPUrlConnection.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging you can see the xml following the tips on the wiki.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#How_to_see_raw_xml_request_and_response_e.g._for_debugging?

For parsing you should not parse manually and you should not use bodyIn but rather getResponse on envelope.